# Overflowing Binary to Decimal Function

Tags: excel, vba

When I send in the string `1111101110001110` as the binary form of the number that I want, I get an

> Error Overflow

in the code. Which in decimal would be `64398`. I am returning it to an integer in the main function. This number should be small enough as to not overflow the integer right? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Function Bin2Dec(ByVal Binarystring As String) As Integer ' This converts a binary to a decimal
    Dim X As Integer
    For X = 0 To Len(Binarystring) - 1
        Bin2Dec = CDec(Bin2Dec) + Val(Mid(Binarystring, _
                  Len(Binarystring) - X, 1)) * 2 ^ X
    Next
End Function
```

Comment: `Integer` in VBA is 2-Byte (historic reasons) and it's value range is from -32.768 to 32.767 - Change return type from `Integer` to `Long`.

Comment: Thank you, I must have been miswording my google searches and kept seeing that it could be larger than that.